# Docker Cloud Automated Build - Automatically Publish an Image for a Pull Request

Tags: dockerhub, docker-cloud

I am exploring the automated build features of the ["New Docker Hub"](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).

I see that it is possible to trigger automated tests for each new pull request that is submitted against a specific branch.

Is it possible to push/publish the images created from a specific pull request?

If this was possible, an open source project could invite folks to test pull requests without needing to re-build the code for a pull request.